# Expected number of edges in the neighborhood of vertices in random graphs

Tags: random-graphs

**Question:**

> given a vertex $v$ of a symmetric random graph $G$ without self loops and parallel edges, what is the expected number edges in the subgraph induced by the vertices $u\in G\setminus v:\ (u,v)\in G$?

The model of the random graph is intentionally left open, but the Erdös-Renyi may be assumed.

Comment: Well, in $G(n,p)$, any such edge is included with probability $p^3$, hence the expected number is $p^3\binom{n-1}2$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: In $G(n,M)$, I get $\frac{M(M-1)(M-2)}{\binom n2\left(\binom n2-1\right)\left(\binom n2-2\right)}\binom{n-1}2$.